# Spring Integration Testing of Outbound Http Enpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I am new to the Spring Integration project, now I need to create a flow with Java DSL and test it.
I came up with these flows. First one should run by cron and invoke second one, which invokes HTTP endpoint and translates XML response to POJO:

```
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow pollerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(() -> new GenericMessage<>(""),
            e -> e.poller(p -> p.cron(this.cron)))
        .channel("pollingChannel")
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow flow(HttpMessageHandlerSpec bulkEndpoint) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("pollingChannel")
        .enrichHeaders(authorizationHeaderEnricher(user, password))
        .handle(bulkEndpoint)
        .transform(xmlTransformer())
        .channel("httpResponseChannel")
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  HttpMessageHandlerSpec bulkEndpoint() {
    return Http
        .outboundGateway(uri)
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
        .errorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler());
  }
```

Now I want to test flow and mock HTTP call, but struggling to mock HTTP handler, I tried to do it like that:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = {"pollerFlow"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FlowConfiguration.class)
public class FlowTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;
  @Autowired
  public DirectChannel httpResponseChannel;
  @Autowired
  public DirectChannel pollingChannel;

  @Test
  void test() {
    final MockMessageHandler mockHandler = MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()
        .handleNextAndReply(message -> new GenericMessage<>(xml, message.getHeaders()));
    mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("bulkEndpoint", mockHandler);
    httpResponseChannel.subscribe(message -> {
      assertThat(message.getPayload(), is(notNullValue()));
      assertThat(message.getPayload(), instanceOf(PartsSalesOpenRootElement.class));
    });

    pollingChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>(""));
  }
}
```

But I am always getting an error, that on line:

> mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("bulkEndpoint", mockHandler);

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'bulkEndpoint' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.endpoint.IntegrationConsumer' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler'
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I am assuming I have a problem with IntegrationFlow itself, or maybe my testing approach is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct. The `bulkEndpoint` is not an endpoint by itself. It is really a `MessageHandler`. The endpoint is created from the `.handle(bulkEndpoint)`.
See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#finding-class-names-for-java-and-dsl-configuration and https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-mocks.

So, to make it working you need to do something like this:

```
.handle(bulkEndpoint, e -> e.id("actualEndpoint"))
```

And then in the test:

```
mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("actualEndpoint", mockHandler);
```

You also probably need to think to not have that `pollerFlow` to be started when you test it sine you send the message into `pollingChannel` manually. So, there is no conflicts with what you'd like to test. For this reason you also add a `id()`  into your `e.poller(p -> p.cron(this.cron))` and use `@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup)` to have it stopped before your test. I see you try `noAutoStartup = {"pollerFlow"}`, but this is not going to help for static flows. You indeed need to have stopped an actual endpoint in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I also was able to add channels in between endpoints and test code between 2 endpoints, but this approach I like more.